# "java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can not perform this action after onSaveInstanceState" on fragmentTransaction.commit()

Tags: java, android

I couldn't seem to get my head around this one. I have already gone through possible solutions Stack Overflow has to offer.

I have 2 activities, say, A and B; when I go back to A from B and then selecting an image come back to B, none of the fragment transaction works and throws error as shown below.

Code:

MainMenuFragment.java

```
 @Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()){
        case R.id.menu_filter:
            activity.changeMode(EditImageActivity.MODE_FILTERS);
            activity.sliderFragment.resetBitmaps();
            activity.changeMiddleFragment(EditImageActivity.MODE_FILTERS);
            break;
        case R.id.menu_enhance:
            activity.changeMode(EditImageActivity.MODE_ENHANCE);
            activity.sliderFragment.resetBitmaps();
            activity.changeMiddleFragment(EditImageActivity.MODE_ENHANCE);
            break;
        case R.id.menu_adjust:
            activity.changeMode(EditImageActivity.MODE_ADJUST);
            activity.changeMiddleFragment(EditImageActivity.MODE_ADJUST);
            break;
        case R.id.menu_sticker:
            activity.changeMode(EditImageActivity.MODE_STICKER_TYPES);
            activity.changeMiddleFragment(EditImageActivity.MODE_STICKER_TYPES);
            break;
        case R.id.menu_write:
            activity.changeMode(EditImageActivity.MODE_WRITE);
            activity.changeMiddleFragment(EditImageActivity.MODE_WRITE);
            break;
    }
}
```

EditImageActivity.java

```
 public void changeMiddleFragment(int index) {
        FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        transaction.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.slide_up, R.anim.slide_down);
        transaction.replace(R.id.preview_container, getFragment(index, this));
        transaction.commit();
}
```

Error:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
     Process: org.ArtIQ.Rex, PID: 9739
     java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can not perform this action after onSaveInstanceState
         at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.checkStateLoss(FragmentManager.java:1842)
         at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.enqueueAction(FragmentManager.java:1860)
         at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.commitInternal(BackStackRecord.java:650)
         at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.commit(BackStackRecord.java:609)
         at org.ArtIQ.Rex.editor.EditImageActivity.changeMiddleFragment(EditImageActivity.java:392)
         at org.ArtIQ.Rex.editor.fragment.MainMenuFragment.onClick(MainMenuFragment.java:82)
         at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5637)
         at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22429)
         at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
         at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119)
         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
```

Comment: Please post you actual code flow, the code that you have posted is not enough to know what you're trying to do

Comment: When exactly (in terms of activity lifecycle) changeMiddleFragment is called?

Comment: Updated the code, its called on onClick()

Answer (score 0):

Changing `transaction.commit()` to `transaction.commitAllowingStateLoss()` should resolve this.